# RewriteCond expr with Optional parts and Server variables

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

In my quest for "hotlinking protection" I am comparing REFERER to HOST and I want to allow for optional PORT (3000) in REFERER.

I have 2 candidates for this job, both lacking something.

```
RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}/*'"
RewriteCond expr "%{HTTP_REFERER} !~ m#.*?://%{HTTP_HOST}(:3000)?/.*?#"
```

Apache's docs did not help much so...

1st line uses -strmatch, which as far as I know does not support optional parts - similar to regex `(:3000)?`. It supports only wildcard *,? and []. For which I did not found any specs - from my exps * matches any string incl. empty one, ? should be any single character and [] can be used for char ranges similar to regex.

2nd line uses regex (!~,=~), which would be just great, but I cannot find a way to insert the HTTP_HOST server variable into it.

Anyone has some experience on how to either have optional part in strmatch or insert server var into regex.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from this [official doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html) that regpattern doesn't allow use of variables. It is only defined as:

```
regpattern ::= cstring ; except enclosing regsep
```

You can use this work-around to get your job done by combining both variable in conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTP_REFERER} ^([^#]+)#.*//:\1(:3000)?/.*$
```

Here `\1` is back-reference of first capture group i.e. `([^#]+)` which represents `%{HTTP_HOST}` value.

---

Another option is to use `&&` and have 2 conditions:

```
RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}/*' && ! %{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}:3000/*"
```

Comment: This is a solution (somewhat hacky though). However expr is supported in RewriteCond, at least on my dev an my webhosting apache and the first line is fully functional in that form. It just does not acknowledge the port.

Comment: You're right. I checked in latest Apache and it is supported. Let me update my answer.

Comment: It appears from this doc: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html that `regpattern` doesn't allow use of variables. It is only defined as: `regpattern  ::= cstring ; except enclosing regsep`